# php ORDER BY date doesn't seem to work

Tags: php, mysql

I want to display only the books whose discount is current. Dealstart and Dealend represent the window. But I'm messing something up.

```
$sqlCommand = "SELECT id,bookcover FROM booklist WHERE category1='$bookid' OR category2='$bookid' OR category3='$bookid' AND dealstart >= CURDATE() AND dealend is >= CURDATE()";
```

Comment: group your `OR` condition. [Read about operator precedence](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html).

Comment: There is no ORDER BY in your query

Comment: That solved it. I put () around my OR statements. Thank you.

Comment: I really hope you have some [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/) in there.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's a syntax error in your SQL statement, remove the "is":

```
lCommand = "SELECT id,bookcover FROM booklist WHERE category1='$bookid' OR category2='$bookid' OR category3='$bookid' AND dealstart >= CURDATE() AND dealend >= CURDATE()";
```

If the query still doesn't work, echo "lCommand" and see what it's producing, then try running that query against your database.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
$sqlCommand = "SELECT
                   id,
                   bookcover
               FROM
                   booklist
               WHERE
                   category1='$bookid' OR
                   category2='$bookid' OR
                   category3='$bookid' AND
                   dealstart >= CURDATE() AND
                   dealend >= CURDATE()
               ORDER BY
                   dealend DESC";
```